# BLE connectGatt() method is not reporting anything in BluetoothGattCallback....?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Can somebody please check the problem with this code. I have implemented a service and passes a `BluetoothDevice` object to it (There is no error/Problem in `BluetoothDevice` object passing through intent). Then, in the `onStartCommand()`, i am calling `deviceToConnect.connectGatt(this,false,mGattCallback)`. But my `BluetoothGattCallback()` is not working (Not printing anything). Code is simple and straight forward. Can somebody help me to debug it.

EDIT: i am doing Le device Scan in `MainActivity()` and passing device object to a service to connect to the device.

```
public class PairedBleService extends Service
{
    private BluetoothGatt mConnectedGatt;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        BluetoothDevice deviceToConnect = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(DEVICE_TO_CONNECT);
        mConnectedGatt = deviceToConnect.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service End", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Peripheral connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS && newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Peripheral Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            gatt.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I tried to connect my beacon (Peripheral) with standard android bluetooth s/w and there i am able to make connection. But there it is asking for Pairing pin and once putting the pin it is connected and shown in Paired bluetooth device. Is there any method like `connectGatt` where we can ask "pairing pin" to the user... I am unable to understand what i am missing.

Comment: Where do you scan for devices ?

Comment: Scanning i have done in my activity and I am passing BluetoothDevice object into service to connect to it.

Comment: Have you put in an unconditional Toast or log in onConnectionStateChange to make sure it is getting called at all?

Comment: Hi @DouglasJones... I tried that also, But no printable Toast message... Please look at Edited Part of the Question... May be it help.

Comment: Have you got solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your onBind method is returning null and hence your main activity is not able to communicate with your service.

Your code should be as per the below,

**@ PairedBleService**

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder 
{
    PairedBleService getService() 
    {
        return PairedBleService.this;
    };
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mBinder;
};

private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
```

**@ Main Activity**

```
//put this inside onServiceConnected

PairedBleService bleService = ((PairedBleService.LocalBinder) service).getService();

// Your code for connecting with BLE device
....................................
....................................
```

Comment: Thanx for ur response vikram... But I am unable to understand yet.. Because i am able to connect to service but BluetoothGattCallback is not calling i.e. Toast messages are not showing in onConnectionStateChange()........

Answer (score 1):

The edit does help. You want to pair from within the app...

`BluetoothDevice` has a `createBond()` method as of API level 19 (4.4) so this leaves out 4.3 which was the first BLE Android version, but there aren't many of those left.

That should pop up the PIN dialog for the user. Once the device is successfully bonded you can then connect. To know when bonding has completed or not you need to have a `BroadcastReceiver` that is registered to listen to `ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED`. The `Intent` that comes in has `EXTRA_BOND_STATE` which can be `BOND_BONDED`, `BOND_BONDING_`, or `BOND_NONE`.

So in your `onStartCommand` you want to `getBondState()` and if it is `BOND_NON` you want to `createBond()`. If it is `BOND_BONDING` you need to wait for the bonding with the `BroadcastReceiver` and connect once it is bonded. If it is `BOND_BONDED` then you can connect.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. I would retrieve a BluetoothDevice by MAC address, which was saved to SharedPrefs after a previous scan by the user so we can connect automatically to this device when our app is opened.

After getting the BluetoothDevice, I then I called `device.connectGatt(...)`, and the callback would never be hit and the connection attempt would hang forever.

It turns out there is an internal Bluetooth device cache in the Android OS. Rebooting your phone and toggling bluetooth off and back on seem to clear this cache, and any past scan results are no longer present in the cache.

If you attempt to call `device.connectGatt(...)` using a `BluetoothDevice` that is no longer in the cache, the `connectGatt` call will hang forever, and your callback won't be hit.

Instead, you need to check the `type` of the `BluetoothDevice`. If the type is `BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_UNKNOWN` then you need to perform a BLE scan before you try to connect, since the device is no longer in the cache.

Here's a snippet of my code that fixes this issue once and for all!

```
//Retrieve the MAC address of the device you want to connect to...in my case I used SharedPreferences
val pairedMacAddress = AppPreferences.getStringPreference(this, AppPreferences.PREF_BT_MAC_ADDRESS)
val savedBleDevice = bluetoothManager.adapter.getRemoteDevice(pairedMacAddress)
Timber.i("BluetoothDevice type is: ${savedBleDevice.type}")

// Saved BLE device is no longer in the device cache, we need to scan for devices again in order to autoconnect.
if (savedBleDevice.type == BluetoothDevice.DEVICE_TYPE_UNKNOWN) {

    Timber.i("Scanning for BLE devices since the saved BLE device is no longer in the system's BT cache.")

    val macAddressFilter = ScanFilter.Builder()
            .setDeviceAddress(pairedMacAddress)
            .build()

    val scanSettings = ScanSettings.Builder()
            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
            .build()

    bluetoothManager.adapter.bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(listOf(macAddressFilter), scanSettings, object : ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {

            Timber.w("Got scan results!")

            with(result.device) {
                Timber.i("Found BLE device! Name: ${name ?: "Unnamed"}, address: $address, going to connect now.")
                startBleConnection(this) // This calls device.connectGatt()
            }
        }

        override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            Timber.e("onScanFailed: code $errorCode")
        }
    })
} else {
    Timber.i("Saved BluetoothDevice is still in the BT cache. Auto-connecting!")
    startBleConnection(savedBleDevice) // This calls device.connectGatt()
}
```

Bluetooth on Android is fun - good luck!

Comment: For it was because I was using bt classic scanner and then the device was saved as a type = 1 = Classic, which connect gatt didn't want to work with it.